# Ubuntu 12.04: getting a list of packages that have updates

Tags: linux, ubuntu, updates

Is there a way to get a list of available updates to a file in Ubuntu 12.04?

I need this in order to review the update list before making the update so if something goes wrong I have at least some kind of idea on where the problem might be.

In essence the use case would be as following:

1. Get a list of available updates
2. Review the list and mark potentially problematic packages
3. Perform the update

If problems occur, start troubleshooting from the previously marked packages.

Comment: The output of apt-get upgrade and of apt-get dist-upgrade shows you the packages about to be upgraded. Why can't you obtain the information you need there?

Comment: It does show the list but does it also save it to a file?  Would sudo echo apt-get update > updates.txt work?

Comment: No, it wouldn't because it stops for user input. But you can use instead sudo apt-get upgrade --dry-run > pkg_list.txt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand your question. There are no updates to `files` in Linux, only to packages. If you wish to check which update might change a specific file you have in mind, you can do it like this.

First, this command

```
   sudo apt-get upgrade --dry-run
```

will provide you with a list of packages to be upgraded, without performing `any` operation. The following command will then only download the packages in question

```
   sudo apt-get upgrade --download-only
```

Now that you have you packages safely in your vault (which, BTW, is located at /var/cache/apt/archives) you may check the files any package will have to update by
means of the command

```
   dpkg-deb -c package_name.deb
```

The `-c` option means this:

> -c, --contents archive
>
> Lists  the contents of the filesystem tree archive portion of the package archive. It is
>                 currently produced in the format generated by tar's verbose listing.

When you are satisfied all is well, you may install the package with

```
   sudo dpkg -i package_name.deb
```

All of this can be easily scripted, of course. I hope this is what you were after.

Answer (score 0):

Software updater has a "details of updates" option which will give you a list of the updates it is about to install. Otherwise `sudo apt-get upgrade` will give you a list, less security updates.